# Linux Regex - Removing files

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I want to remove all the files which end with a '~' in a directory which has several sub directories.

Is there any safe way to do this?

Comment: Be aware that testing the answers below should be done in a TEST environment.  One accidental typo and you could be wiping out a lot of data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try:

```
find <directory in question> -name "*~" -delete
```

Where `<directory in question>` should be the top most directory where you say you have a lot of sub directories.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` to find them and `rm` to remove them. For example, under `/tmp`:

```
   find /tmp -name *~ -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Actually, in this case, it's better to use `-delete` like in Fred's answer, but I'll leave this because it shows how you could use `find` to execute any command on the files it finds, not just `rm`.